# css is not being applied after handling it in the local server

Tags: node.js

i'm node.js beginner, i handled main.css endpoint in the server side but CSS still not applied in the page ,

this is the link tag i used in html , and my css file is not sent over the browser, but when i type  localhost:3000/main.css the main.css file the being shown!

(the response was the main.css file it self but idk why its not applied when when the end point is"/" its just applied the html file without css! can you please help me find the 
problem and i'll be thankful

```js
const router = (request, response) => {
  const endpoint = request.url;
  if(endpoint == "/"){
    const filepath = path.join(__dirname , "..", "public", "index.html" )
    fs.readFile(filepath, (error, file) => {
      if(error){
        response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('<h1>theres an internal error</h1>');  

      }else{
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end(file);  

      }
    })
  }else if(path.extname(endpoint)) {
    const extention = path.extname(endpoint);
    const extentionType = {
      ".css": "text/css",
      ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
      ".js": "text/javascript"
    }
    const filepath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "public", endpoint);

    fs.readFile(filepath, (error, file) => {
      if(error){
        response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('<h1>theres an internal error</h1>');  

      }else{
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': extentionType[extention] });
        response.end(file); 
      }
      
    })
  }
  else{
    response.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(`<h1>page not found</h1>`);  
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, your code is vulnerable to URLs with `/../` in them that allow an attacker to explore parts of your hard disk outside of the `public` directory you intend.  This is one of the reasons it's often better to use something like Express where `express.static()` for serving static files already has this type of protection built in rather than you writing your own code from scratch to solve a problem that has already been solved many times before.  It also already sends the right content type for you automatically.

Comment: What is `req.url` when the browser requests your main.css file?  What does the `<link>` tag look like in your HTML page that specifies `main.css`?

Comment: To debug yourself, look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger when your page is loaded and see EXACTLY what your server returns for anything the browser requests on that page.  Also, add `console.log()` statements to each branch of your request handler so you can see exactly what the server is doing.

Comment: Also, when the browser requests `/favicon.ico` or when a search engine requests `/robots.txt` or any other URL request that you don't have direct support for, you're going to return a 500 instead of a 404 which is not correct.

Comment: my req.url is "/" .. my link tag in html file is <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text\css">
this is the link tag i used in html , and my css file is not sent over thebrowser, but when i type  localhost:3000/main.css the main.css file the being shown!

Comment: <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text\css">
this is the link tag i used in html , and my css file is not sent over thebrowser, but when i type  localhost:3000/main.css the main.css file the being shown!

Comment: Your link tag should be this: `<link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`.  Note: two small changes.

Comment: it worked, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've shown you actual link tag, you should change it from this:

```
<link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text\css">
```

to this:

```
<link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

---

Also, when the browser requests `/favicon.ico` or when a search engine requests `/robots.txt` or any other URL request that you don't have direct support for, you're going to return a 500 instead of a 404 which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather comment, but I don't have enough points.

Few suggestions:

Ensure your CSS file is sent over to your browser.
Review your CSS link href attribute in the HTML is pointing to the correct path.

You can test both by viewing the inspector tool in your browser for network activity, and also viewing the source.

Comment: <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text\css">
this is the link tag i used in html , and my css file is not sent over thebrowser, but when i type  localhost:3000/main.css the main.css file the being shown!